# how do I get my wifi password out of Vista when "STATUS" is greyed out?

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-vista, passwords, windows-registry

*NOTA BENE!
this question is different than the one suggested, because:*

*1. I am not connected, this is the whole point of my question.*

*2. I specifically asked about the situation where the **STATUS** option is greyed out, as in: INACTIVE, which is not in the other question.*

========BEGIN=OF=QUESTION========

I've tried this method:
http://www.howtogeek.com/116934/how-to-view-that-forgotten-wireless-network-password-in-windows/
and it works okay on other machines, but on my **Vista Vista Vista Vista Vista Vista HP pavillion DV2** it doesn't work because on the context menu for the Wifi connection, the **status** option is greyed out. so .on the third picture, there's no status there.

questions:

1. is there a command line method of getting this?
2. can i see it in the registry?
3. or how else do i solve this?

I should say that presumeably, the wifi is broken in a hardware/physical sense, i can make ethernet access, but now i've got a new laptop, so I want to extract the wifi password out of the old laptop.
Did I mention it's a **Vista** OS?
========END=OF=QUESTION========

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find out the Wi-Fi password once already connected?](http://superuser.com/questions/871759/how-to-find-out-the-wi-fi-password-once-already-connected)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is the wifi password stored somewhere in windows-7?](http://superuser.com/questions/424624/is-the-wifi-password-stored-somewhere-in-windows-7)

Comment: See this answer and the one below it....http://superuser.com/a/825426/40928

Comment: regarding *"Is the wifi password stored somewhere in windows-7"*  Did you even READ my question? It was about Vista, not Win7. They are different OSes ....
I appreciate your effort, but if you can't be bothered with important specifics like what type of OS it's about ...